# Unable to add elements to Hashtable

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, hashtable

I'm new to C# (I'm using C# 5 according to the Visual Studio 2013 command line). After following some tutorials on the Microsoft site I'm running into an issue:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

public class Hashtable {

    public static void Main() {
        Hashtable employees = new Hashtable();

        employees.Add("111-222-333","Matt");
        employees.Add("222-333-444","Steve");
        employees.Add("123-432-123","Adam");

        if(employees.ContainsKey("111-222-333")) {
            string empName = (string) employees["111-222-333"];
            Console.WriteLine("Employee 111-222-333's name is: " + empName);
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine("Employee 111-222-333 is not in the hash table.");
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to compile this I get an error which states:

> 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type
>   'Hashtable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

I'm totally confused. I can't find anything that suggests I should be doing something different.

Comment: Don't call your own class `Hashtable`.

Comment: That was an easy fix (stupid move). Thanks.

Comment: Consider using [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx), which supports generics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because your class name is named Hashtable so it is using that instead of the c# bcl Hashtable implementation. Specify System.Collection.Hashtable to explicitly use the bcl hashtable.